# My laptop causes the wireless router to stop working

Tags: router, wireless-networking, networking

it's happening something strange to my wireless connection. The wireless connection works fine with all the devices at home, except with my laptop (Toshiba satellite, WIN 7 64): as I start it, the wireless network shuts off and the connection disappears also for the other devices.

I can use internet only plugging the laptop with an ethernet cable, and I have to shut off the wireless card, to allow the other people in the house to use the wireless connection.

I tried to update the firmware (it is a D-Link DIR 615) but it's up to date, and reconfigure the router, but all indicates that the problem is caused by my laptop. I'm currently doing an antivirus scanning, but the computer seems to be clean.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you running wireless n?

Comment: Yes, it's Wireless N

Comment: Maybe the card is bad, and it is constantly transmitting an interfering signal.  Switch with a known good card and see what happens.

Comment: Fred has no idea what he is talking about.